# iOS6 vs iOS7 font rendering issue

Tags: ios6, fonts, ios7

I've got a really strange font rendering issue. In my app I am using a cutom font "Bariol". When you look at the screenshot comparison between iOS6 and iOS7 you'll see that first the spacings (line spacing and also letter spacing) differ between iOS 6 and 7. But what is really weird is that the small letter "g" is different. The one on iOS 7 is actually the correct letter. I only noticed now that I am building with Xcode 5 that in iOS 6 the system was always substituting that letter.

[image]

1. Does anyone know why the letter substitution would happen under iOS6, and which font the OS is choosing?
2. Can I enforce the same letter/word/line spacing in iOS7 as in iOS6? Because some screens look off with the new spacing.

Comment: Per iOS 7 release note, [UIFont lingHeight] on iOS 7 is different form iOS 6 and there will be noticeable visual differences.

Comment: @JoeSmith Could you please provide a line, because I have had a look in the iOS7 release notes and it says nothing about UIFont lineHeight being different from iOS6.

Comment: @NebulaFox, I can't find the note about it either in the latest version of iOS 7 release note. I think it is in one of the previous versions for the iOS 7 betas. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get a copy of those. If you no longer have the problem, probably it is been fixed in latest iOS 7 build.

Answer (score 1):

Your "g" is being replaced by the default Helvetica font in iOS6, but no idea why.